# Why does localtunnel not work when there is a redirect defined for a route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, localtunnel

These devices are all on the same LAN:

- Ubuntu server
- Win 10 PC
- iPhone
- Android

On the Ubuntu server, the `/etc/hosts` file has:

```
127.0.0.1       rcw.lt
```

Also on the Ubuntu server, there is a Laravel app hosted by nginx: `server_name rcw.lt;`.

The `/` homepage route of my rcw.lt app uses a redirect (see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-redirect).

I run `lt --port 80 --local-host rcw.lt &`.

**What does NOT work:**

- When browsing from Win 10 or iPhone or Android to the URL generated for the rcw.lt app (such as https://fat-tiger-93.loca.lt), it always tries to redirect to https://rcw.lt (and says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

**What works:**

- I can browse to the provided generated URL and append a specific path onto it (such as https://fat-tiger-93.loca.lt/some-specific-route), and it works. Or I can remove the redirect from the `/` route (which I don't want to do).

Any ideas?

**Is this a problem with how Laravel redirects work? Or a problem with localtunnel? Is there a workaround?**

I really appreciate your help. :-)

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: @pasanjg not yet

Comment: found any solutions yet?  I has he same questions.